# Есть ли ошибки в тексте?

Tags: грамотная-речь, не-или-ни

Нас привязала ни наша планета, ни наша время проведенное вместе, меня притягивало к ней, только ее способность, видеть то, что другие не замечают, или вовсе не хотят замечать. во время нашего разговора, она рассказала мне о таких звездах, как она, они были идеальными как кристаллы, как внешне так и внутри, но их идеальность для них казалось что-то простым, идеальные всегда скромнье. Мы разговаривали с ней всю ночь, она заставляла меня улыбнуться по-другому, и плакать как все.

Comment: Я исправила ошибки, но Вам нужно изменить шрифт в вопросе.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: Саша, будьте добры, в знак уважения к отвечающим на Ваши вопросы, перепишите текст, используя строчные буквы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибок действительно много, но **содержание мне понравилось: текст написан очень искренне, от души.** Вам нужно серьезно заняться правописанием, но **литературные способности у Вас, как я думаю, есть**.

**После редактирования** (исправлены ошибки и немного поправлен стиль):

**Вариант 1**

Нас связали ни наша планета, ни наше время, проведенное вместе, ―  меня притягивала к ней только ее способность видеть то, что не замечают другие или просто не хотят замечать.

Во время нашего разговора она рассказала о таких звездах, как она. **Они идеальны, как кристаллы, как внешне, так и внутренне.  Но их совершенство кажется им чем-то обыкновенным ― идеальные всегда скромные.**

Мы разговаривали с ней всю ночь, и она заставила меня улыбаться по-другому и плакать, как все.

**Вариант 2 (исправленный)**

Нас связали ни наша планета, ни наше время, проведенное вместе, ―  меня притягивала к ней только ее способность видеть то, что не замечают другие или просто не хотят замечать.

Во время нашего разговора она рассказала о таких звездах, как она. **Они похожи на идеальные кристаллы как внешне, так и внутренне, но их совершенство кажется им чем-то обыкновенным, они всегда ненавязчивы и скромны.**

Мы разговаривали с ней всю ночь, и она заставила меня улыбаться по-другому и плакать, как все.

**Примечание**

Если Вас интересуют конкретные исправления, то Вы можете спросить об этом дополнительно.

Comment: Жасмин спасибо вам ! У меня есть ещё вопросы по этой теме. Как я могу напрямую связаться с вами ?

Comment: Давайте попробуем сначала всё выяснить здесь (у меня просто нет специальной почты для связи). В этом же вопросе  (нажмите кнопку "исправить") дополнительно перепишите еще раз текст в другом шрифте и пометьте цифрами неясные места: (1), (2) и т.д. Также можете добавить текстовые вопросы. Я дам Вам еще один ответ (уже по конкретным вопросам). Кстати, и другие участники смогут при желании присоединиться.

Comment: @Jasmin, это вы серьезно?! Про литературные способности? А вот это действительно исправление: "Нас связала ни наша планета, ни наше время..." Вообще-то, за такое в школе ставят единицы.

Comment: @Jasmin, это вы серьезно?! Про литературные способности? А вот это действительно исправление: "Нас связала ни наша планета, ни наше время..." Вообще-то, за такое в школе ставят единицы. Можно было бы вот так: нас НЕ связывала НИ наша планета, НИ ещё чего-то там.

Comment: Про литературные способности  я говорю абсолютно серьезно: эмоции, который испытывает герой,  описаны интересно, нестандартно, выразительно.  И про грамотность. Не ставят единицы за НИ...НИ в школе (правда, это смотря какая школа). Союз НИ...НИ включает частицу НИ с усилительным значением. Обязательное НЕ  используется при противопоставлении: Нас связала не планета, не время, а нечто другое.

Comment: @Jasmin, нда... Описано интересно. "Во время нашего разговора она рассказала о таких звездах, как она" – шедевр. Они идеальны, как кристаллы, как внешне, так и внутренне. Два кака и один так в одной фразе – не чересчур ли?

Comment: Здесь Вы правы, стилевые погрешности имеют место, но Пушкин с Толстым тоже не с первого листа печатали свои шедевры. Исправим чуть позже, и  для автора будет хорошей школой. Может быть, свой вариант предложите?

Comment: Это уж увольте. Свой вариант могу предложить только такой: не графоманить. Знаете, писАть, как и пИсать, нужно только тогда, когда невмоготу.

Answer (score 3):

Из ответа **Jasmin**:

> Нас связали ни наша планета, ни наше время...

Здесь нужна частица ***не***:

***Нас связали не наша планета, не наше время...***

См. [***"Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник"***](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=42#pp42):

> **§ 77…** Основная функция частицы ***ни*** — усиление отрицания. Поэтому она употребляется в предложениях с отрицательным сказуемым, т.
>   е. сказуемым, включающим частицу ***не*** или выраженным словами
>   ***нельзя, нет***.

Отрицательного сказуемого в разбираемом нами предложении нет. Нужна частица ***не***.

Comment: Ответ неполный. Кроме основной функции есть еще значение соединительного союза.  *Ни тихо, ни громко течёт рассказ*,  *Елисей был старичок ни богатый, ни бедный (Л. Толстой).* (https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/73/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B8#sel=11:26,11:31;11:68,11:78) Однако я все равно думаю, что это не наш случай: в приведенных примерах отсутствует противопоставление, альтернатива, а в нашем случае она есть.

Answer (score 1):

Мое понимание ситуации отличается от представленного в ответе Jasmin. По-моему, требуется частица *не*. Я вижу здесь именно противопоставление: нас связала не планета, не время, а ее способность видеть то, что не замечают другие. Вариант исправления:

**Нас связала не наша планета и не время, проведенное нами вместе, ― меня притягивала к ней только ее способность видеть то, что другие не замечают или просто не хотят замечать.**